# Charge conservation

Tags: voltage, capacitor, capacitance, charge, charge-pump

How can I apply the theory of charge conservation for this charge pump circuit. Specifically on the pump circuit. How do I get the charges on the capacitors?[image]

Comment: Which capacitors?

Comment: Capacitors Cx, C1,C2,C3,C4 in the pumping circuit @Andyaka